# Como pegar a data correta para o próximo evento

Tags: php, data

Eu tenho uma lista com os dias da semana que mostra quando deve ocorrer um evento e uma outra variável com o intervalo que deve ocorrer esse evento, por exemplo, se na lista estiver `0,1,0,1,0,1,0` [seg-qua-sex] irá ocorrer os eventos, e se nessa minha variável de intervalo eu tiver o valor de `2` isso significa que deverá ocorrer semana sim semana não.

O que preciso é saber quando irá ocorrer o próximo evento, será que alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso, o meu problema é bem mais complexo, mas tentei deixar o mais simples possível mas estou apanhando nessa parte.

Answer (score 1):

De uma maneira procedural, apenas com as informações da pergunta:

```
$intervalo = 2; //2 em 2 semanas
$semanaAtual = array(0,0,1,0,0,0,0); //domingo, segunda, terça, quarta, quinta, sexta, sábado
$semanaProxima = array(0,0,0,1,0,0,0); //domingo, segunda, terça, quarta, quinta, sexta, sábado

$ultimoEvento = '2016-02-23'; //string contendo a data do último evento
$diaDaSemana = date("w", strtotime($ultimoEvento)); //dia da semana em que ocorreu o último evento
$dataProximoEvento = ''; //data do próximo evento

//verifica se dentro da própria semana ainda ocorrerá o evento
for($i=$diaDaSemana+1; $i<=6; $i++) {
    if($semanaAtual[$i]) {
        $dataProximoEvento = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($ultimoEvento . ' + ' . ($i-$diaDaSemana) . ' days'));
        break;
    }
}

//verifica qual o próximo dia do evento na próxima semana de acordo com o intervalo
if(empty($dataProximoEvento)) {
    $primeiroDiaSemana = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last Sunday", strtotime($ultimoEvento . ' + ' . (7*$intervalo) . ' days') )));

    for($i=0; $i<=6; $i++) {
        if($semanaProxima[$i]) {
            $dataProximoEvento = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($primeiroDiaSemana->modify("+$i days")->format("Y-m-d H:i")));
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo $dataProximoEvento;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma

```
<?php
$regra_frequencia = '0,1,0,1,0,1,0'; 
$dow = explode(",", $regra_frequencia);
$dow_now = date('w');
$dow_repeat = array();
$intervalo = 2;

foreach($dow as $w => $on) {    
    if($on == 1) {
        $dow_repeat[] = $w;
    }
}

$dow_get = $dow_repeat[0];

if($dow_now < 6) {  
    foreach($dow_repeat as $d) {
        if($d > $dow_now) {
            $dow_get = $d;
            break;          
        }       
    }
}

$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));

if($dow_get > $dow_now) {
    $diff = $dow_get - $dow_now;
    $date->add(new DateInterval("P" . $diff . "D"));
    $dt_next_event = $date->format('Y-m-d');
} else {
    $diff = $dow_now - $dow_get;
    $date->sub(new DateInterval("P" . $diff . "D"));
    $date->add(new DateInterval("P" . $intervalo . "W"));
    $dt_next_event = $date->format('Y-m-d');    
}

echo $dt_next_event;
```

Comment: E se a frequência for diferente para cada semana? E se na mesma semana ainda ocorre o evento? Ou isso não era para ser considerado? Veja a resposta que postei.

Comment: Opa Flilipe, obrigado, mas a frequencia é a mesma sempre, se for diferente será outro evento, e no caso que fiz, pelo que testei o usuário pode ocorrer o evento várias vezes na semana, como no exemplo, seg, qua e sex. Será que achou algum erro?

Comment: No exemplo que postei também, podes ter o mesmo evento na mesma semana, basta alterar os arrays.